# I only see the "Other" account option on log in screen

Tags: user-account

So i start up my macbook air after about 3 months of not using it, and i don't see any accounts on the log in screen, except for "Other," and I try to type in my old information, that doesn't work, and there's no option to create an account, so how can i create a new account?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. Why not ask for the solution to your problem rather than for a method to achieve something else?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 10.10 you can use the `sysadminctl` command to create users, assuming you're able to ssh in or something:

```
sudo sysadminctl -addUser username -fullName "User Name" -password - -admin
```